# Quarkus rest-client-reactive unwrap restClientCdiWrapper to restClient?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-reactive

I am having a problem with intercepting some of my rest client method info. For example In my interceptor I want to access parameter annotations in myRestClient method but when I switched to quarkus-restclient-reactive I am getting cdiWrapper. Previously with quarkus-restclient dependency, I was able to access all needed info, but now I am only having access to metadata is there some recommended way how to get needed info in my interceptor or to unwrap wrapped restClientCdiWrapper?

When I start in debug mode I don't get someParameter but arg0 because this is a wrapperClass

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "someKey")
@MyInterceptor
public interface MyRestClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/something")
    User getSomething(@Annotation1 @Annotation2 final String someParameter);
}
```

I am accessing parameters like this in my interceptor

```
final var parameters = context.getMethod().getParameters();
```

Comment: The CDI bean you get extends `RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase` which has the actual implementation in `getDelegate`

Comment: Hi @geoand thanks for the input, can you provide me some example how to get RestClientReactiveCdiWrapperBase and use getDelegate method from javax.interceptor.InvocationContext

Comment: Isn't `RestClientReactiveCdiWrapperBase` the `target` of `InvocationContext`?

Comment: Yes you're right @geoand. I've created RestClientReactiveCdiWrapperBase like this: **final RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase<?> clientWrapper = (RestClientReactiveCDIWrapperBase<?>) context.getTarget();** and now I can execute **.getDelegate()** method which returns me Object. I am still not sure how can I access my parameter annotations from there

Comment: Quarkus copies class-level and method-level annotations from the interface to the generated class. It doesn't copy parameter-level annotations, which it probably should. I'd personally consider this a Quarkus bug.

Comment: @Ladicek indeed, we should probably fix that

Comment: Any info about this bug? @geoand can we check it's state on github?

Comment: It's already been fixed in `3.0.0.CR2` by @Ladicek, see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/32406